# AWS device farm capabilities

Tags: testng, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

Have Appium TestNG IOS tests on my local, am planning to use AWS Device farm, will the below desired capabilities retain on AWS device farm:-

```
cap.setCapability("showXcodeLog", "true");

cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
```

Need the above capabilities as `driver.closeApp()` will uninstall and reinstall the app and will not maintain the app state

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as you use custom environment when scheduling the tests on Device Farm, it will support the desired capabilities you mentioned and others.

Hope that helps.